# Deleting rows in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have recently moved from WinForms to WPF and it seems like handling with datagrids is more complicated here. I have to add the data manually in the datagrid from the user interface when the application runs.

I have following XAML code:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridAdd" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="591,360,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="118" Width="202" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Column="1" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Varenr}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Vare nr.:" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Antal}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Antal" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And the background code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{

    ObservableCollection<Add> list;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        list = new ObservableCollection<Add>();
        dataGridAdd.ItemsSource = list;     
    }

    public class Add
    {
        public string Varenr { get; set; }

        public string Antal { get; set; }
    }

    private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Add addval = dataGridAdd.SelectedItem as Add;

        while (dataGridAdd.Items.Count > 1)
           {
             string vare = addval.Varenr;
             string antal1 = addval.Antal;                                          
             list.Remove(addval);            
           }
    }
}
```

The point is that, when I'm adding data with a single row and pressing on the print button, it deletes the items as expected:

[image]

The issue occurs, when I'm adding multiple rows like:

[image]

The while loop becomes infinite, since the dataGridAdd.Items.Count doesn't go below the value "2" in this case. How can I handle this problem ?.

Comment: Sorry, your code makes no sense. What do you want the variables `vare` and `antal1` for? you're not using them anywhere. Also, the while loop will never finish because you're removing the `SelectedItem` from the DataGrid, which then becomes `null` because a `Selector` cannot have a `SelectedItem` which is not part of it's `ItemsSource` collection. Therefore doing `list.Remove(null);` does absolutely nothing and your while loop never returns. If you want to clear the collection, use `list.Clear();` instead. Please clarify what you're really trying to do here.

Comment: Let me be more concrete then. I'm adding products to a pdf file using the iTextSharp class. The loop first takes the information from the first row (vare and antal1) and adds them to the first line of the pdf document. It then deletes this row and takes the next row and adds the corresponding information to the second line of the document. So it has to run until the datagrid rows becomes empty, so the program knows when to save and print the document. Since there is a lot of code, I just uploaded the part I have an issue with.

Comment: I have also made following modification:

Add addval = dataGridAdd.SelectedItem as Add;

to

Add addval = dataGridAdd.Items[0] as Add;

but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

it is a wrong logic. For example, if you have more than 2 items in dataGridAdd, your code will be excuted like this:

```
    Add addval = dataGridAdd.SelectedItem as Add;

    while (dataGridAdd.Items.Count > 1)
       {
         string vare = addval.Varenr;
         string antal1 = addval.Antal;                                          
         list.Remove(addval);            
       }
```

1. Add addval = dataGridAdd.SelectedItem as Add;
2. while (dataGridAdd.Items.Count > 3)  // dataGridAdd.Items.Count =3 , list.Count =3
3. string vare = addval.Varenr;  string antal1 = addval.Antal;
4. list.Remove(addval);  // return true, remove success, list.count = 2
5. while (dataGridAdd.Items.Count > 2)  //false, dataGridAdd.Items.Count=2
6. string vare = addval.Varenr;  string antal1 = addval.Antal;
7. list.Remove(addval); // return false, remove failed, list.count = 2
   ....

so,the dataGridAdd.Items.Count doesn't go below the value "2"

by the way, why use while in this case?

---

**Update:**

run this code , and you will see `dataGridAdd.SelectedIndex = -1` and `dataGridAdd.SelectedItem = null` after  list.Remove(addval);  so, if you remove again,it will return flase.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                Add addval = dataGridAdd.SelectedItem as Add;


                Console.WriteLine(dataGridAdd.SelectedIndex);
                Console.WriteLine(dataGridAdd.SelectedItem);
                string vare = addval.Varenr;
                string antal1 = addval.Antal;
                list.Remove(addval);
                Console.WriteLine(dataGridAdd.SelectedIndex);
                Console.WriteLine(dataGridAdd.SelectedItem);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just want to know, why the list.Remove(addval) returned 'false" in the second attempt. When I'm adding a single row instead, the Items.Count starts with '2' and goes down to '1' in the second run of the loop.

Comment: when you add a single row,actually dataGridAdd has 2 rows,because you set `dataGridAdd.AutoGenerateRows = true`, if `dataGridAdd.AutoGenerateRows = false ` you can't add rows to dataGridAdd, you could only set dataGridAdd.ItemSource or binding it. `Count starts with '2' and goes down to '1' in the second run of the loop.` is incorrectly, it goes down to '1' in the first run of the loop and break in the second loop. after the first loop,`dataGridAdd.item.count =1` , so it will not excute.

Answer (score 0):

when working with wpf/mvvm you do not remove or add items to your datagrid! you remove and add items to your underlying datasource.

```
  public ObservableCollection<MyDataTypeObjects> MyData {get;set;}

  public MyDataTypeObjects MySelectedData {get;set;}
```

xaml

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedData}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now with following code:

```
private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridAdd.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {                                      
           Add addval = dataGridAdd.Items[i] as Add;
           string vare = addval.Varenr;
           string antal1 = addval.Antal;
        }
        list.Clear();
    }
```